# What impacts your APEX rating?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

I have been playing a lot of multiplayer since it became apparent that the single player doesn't really have much replay value and I've been on a bit of a successful winning streak which has resulted in my APEX rating continually going up.

What impacts your APEX rating? Does it increase by specific amounts based on whether you win or not? Can your APEX rating also go down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To see what affects one's APEX rating, in the multiplayer menu click `Prestige`, then `Challenges`, then scroll down on the left side (under the `General` tab, which is the default) to `Apex Rating - Bronze`.  On the right side it explains:

> Earn a higher APEX Rating by gaining character levels, unlocking higher weapon levels, defeating challenges, extracting from matches, finishing missions, and resetting a character's level.

Comment: so it is influenced by skill but only in that having skill increments the counters it's based off quicker?

Comment: @kalina Sounds right. In ME3 I think it directly corresponded to how many times you had leveled your characters.